# When I do a fresh install of win11 from usb stick, why is bitlocker enabled?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker

asking for a friend,
doing clean install of win11,
& logging in with MS account,
it setups bitlocker,
without being asked,
and it doesn't save the key to the MS account,
nor does it prompt you to save the key,
or tell you it was setup.

tried >three times, on dissimilar hardware,
all fresh installs from usb made using microsoft creator.

it looks like if you turn off bitlocker,
updates turn it on again!

when checking privacy & security,
device encryption (3rd option),

device encryption on
related: bitlocker drive encryption (this takes you to control panel)

seems to be unrelated to home/pro

their question is:

What regular user knows to save the encryption key, if there is no prompt, and it's not done so automatically?

Is there something that windows does on a schedule that pops up a notice to backup the key?

Comment: BitLocker is not nor has it ever been required for Windows Update to function. BitLocker also cannot be enabled on Windows 11 Home.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, the Device Encryption available on Windows Home still uses a "Bitlocker recovery key", so this is comfusing many (including me!).

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: @INN - I am aware. Doesn’t change the fact, Device Encryption which is not BitLocker, nor BitLocker is required for Windows Update to function. Both can also be disabled. I reinstall Windows 10 on a regular basis, so have never had BitLocker, automatically enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It's not BitLocker, it's [Device Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/#device-encryption):

> Unlike a standard BitLocker implementation, **device encryption is
> enabled automatically so that the device is always protected**. When a
> clean installation of Windows is completed and the out-of-box
> experience is finished, the device is prepared for first use. As part
> of this preparation, device encryption is initialized on the OS drive
> and fixed data drives on the computer with a clear key that is the
> equivalent of standard BitLocker suspended state. In this state, the
> drive is shown with a warning icon in Windows Explorer. The yellow
> warning icon is removed after the TPM protector is created and the
> recovery key is backed up.

As you can read on that same page, if you can't find the Bitlocker recovery key in  your MS account, it means that the Disk is encrypted with a clear key which does not need a recovery key.

**Some explanations:** Device Encryption uses the same basic technology as BitLocker. That's why you will still get a "Bitlocker Recovery Key", which can be a bit confusing. The difference between the two is that Bitlocker can encrypt any disks (including USB Sticks etc) which are connected to your device. Device Encryption will only encrypt the internal disks of your device.

If a disk is encrypted with a clear key, it can only be read on the device on which it was encrypted (you can't take it out and put it on a different PC). The thinking behind this is Data Security: if you change the drive on your PC, no one should be able to recover your data from the old drive.

---

Note: *Answer edited, old answer removed*